# Weather forecast using a neural network

Tags: neural-network, prediction, backpropagation

I am trying to write a program for weather forecasting using [backpropagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation). I am a beginner in this field. I have historical data with different parameters like temperature, humidity, wind speed, rainfall etc.

I am confused about how to provide this data to the input layer. Is each input node to be given the whole of the data for a given day, or do I need to have a different network for each parameter? I am also confused about the output layer.

Answer (score 3):

In the input layer have X separate nodes for each dimension (weather, wind, etc) of input data, where X is the number of days to look back to (let's say 4-7). Then you should normalize each input dimension in a suitable range, let's say [-1.0, 1.0].

Have a second "hidden" layer fully interconnected with the first layer (and also with a fix 1.0 input "bias" node to serve as a fix point). There should be less nodes here than in the input layer, but that's just a rule of thumb, you may need to experiment.

The last layer is your output layer fully interconnected with the second layer (and also drop in a bias). Have a separate output neuron for each dimension.

Don't forget to train with the normalized values on both the input and output. Since this is a time series, you may not need to randomize the order of training data but feed them as they come in time - your net will learn the temporal relations also (with luck :)

(Also note that there is a method called "temporal backpropagation" which is tuned for time series data.)

Comment: Would it be correct to assume the more related variables included the more accurate? ie using {Temp, Pressure, Humidity}, better than {Rainfall, Windspeed, UV Index} ?

Comment: @Aaron: It is always better to use more related variables, however if there is a strong relation, the network might be able to learn using other variables too. Also note that transforming some data might be required (for example to log-scale, etc) for the network to study better.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me, that decision trees might be a better solution to this problem than neural networks. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) is a description of how decision trees work. Also, there is software available that has implementations of various classificators including neural networks. I've worked with [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) and it works very well. There are also libraries which you can use to utilize Weka's functionality with programming languages such as Java and C#. If you do decide to work with Weka, make sure you familiarize yourself with the .arff format described [here](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/arff.html).

Comment: If you are interested in using Weka, one option might be to try out Knime, an eclipse based workflow package which includes Weka primitives.

Comment: I'm curious how you'd apply decisions trees to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have used (and own) this book: [Introduction to Neural Networks with Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/097732060X)

I found it a useful reference. It covers quite a spectrum of NN topics, including backpropogation.